# Error on displaying custom registration form view with allauth/django

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to set up different custom registrations for users on a Django. This website was started with cookiecutter.

I get the following error when trying to see this page on my browser

> ```
> TypeError at /users/registrocliente
> FormularioClient() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'
> ```

[image: Error img]

This is my code

on views

```
#View para el formulario de registro de usuarios clientes
class ClienteRegistroView(SignupView):

    template_name = 'templates/account/form_cliente.html'
    form_class = FormularioCliente
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
    view_name = 'registrocliente'
    success_url = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(ClienteRegistroView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ret.update(self.kwargs)
        return ret

registrocliente = ClienteRegistroView.as_view()
```

on forms

```
#Formulario de registro para usuarios del tipo cliente
def FormularioCliente(SignupForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = '__all__'

    def signup(self,request,user):
        user = super(FormularioCliente, self).save(request)
        user = self.cleaned_data['nombre']
        user.pais = self.cleaned_data['pais']
        user.departamento = self.cleaned_data['departamento']
        user.fecha_nacimiento = self.cleaned_data['fecha_nacimiento']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormularioCliente,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

This is the initial version of the form, just starting it off and testing things out before I add more to it.

Comment: you are treating the method FormularioCliente as a class, please check the code, Isn't being showed correctly

Comment: sometimes life makes you feel really dumb, yep that solved it, thanks Mike!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by MikeVelazco

Change that needed to be made was on forms file. I was defining a function instead of a class.

Before
def FormularioCliente(SignupForm):
After
class FormularioCliente(SignupForm):